# Display JSON Map data to pretty print using Jackson

Tags: java, json

When we are using Jackson with SerializationFeature

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

the following output is translates

```
{"employee1":{"id":"1","firstName":"Ranga","lastName":"Reddy"},"employee2":{"id":"2","firstName":"Raja","lastName":"Reddy"}}
```

into

```
{
  "employee1" : {
    "id" : "1",
    "firstName" : "Ranga",
    "lastName" : "Reddy"
  },
  "employee2" : {
    "id" : "2",
    "firstName" : "Raja",
    "lastName" : "Reddy"
  }
}
```

but i want output like these(there should same space between attribute name and value)

```
{
  "employee1" : {
    "id"        : "1",
    "firstName" : "Ranga",
    "lastName"  : "Reddy"
  },
  "employee2" : {
    "id"        : "2",
    "firstName" : "Raja",
    "lastName"  : "Reddy"
  }
}
```

the output is generated above, output is more readable. How to implement this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :-

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Comment: it will gives the 2nd output. but i want 3rd output